# Trade/weapon/armor shop empty

Tags: fallout-4

After I crafted 3 shops in my settlement and assigned some settlers, I tried to buy some things(barter option) but the store seems empty, just like my inventory. Do I have to wait or is there something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it was during business hours?

Comment: Make sure to choose the barter option when in dialogue, and that it is in business hours (8AM-8PM)

Comment: I have found that equipping specific gear helps me quite a bit since the NPCs do not always go where you assign them to. I put bowler hats and clean suits or laundered dresses on all vendors. I put fedora hats on all farmers. I put helmets on guards and yellow helmets on the artillery guys. I put a yellow slacker hat on any settler not assigned yet. This way I can tell if a vendor is in the middle of nowhere and still trade and can also tell if a settler is free to assign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wait for them to restock.  New stores will get inventory after some time.  I had the same issue but after fast traveling and doing some missions my store are now all stocked.

Comment: This is a bug which happens when you build a store and use it at the same day. Every shop restocks their inventory at 0:00, when you use it before, it won't have anything.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug since if you've just set up a store then I wouldn't expect it to have any stock...

Comment: Yeah, agree with @kalina. Definitely sounds like intentional design on the developer's part. Since when is a store ever fully stocked and operational the day after construction finishes?

Comment: @DangerZone is currently anecdotal and I'll test more after class, but I'm completely certain I had a settler at a weapon shop, cleaned her out of caps, told her to man the new clothing stall, scrapped the weapon shop, and she had a completely new inventory and more caps immediately.

Comment: @Dallium, use a fresh settler for a proper test. Otherwise you lack a control for your experiment, which diminishes the meaning of the results.

Comment: @DangerZone that's not really a control. We're dealing with code here, not natural phenomena. Way less variables. If fresh settlers don't get an inventory until 0000, that's a valid experiment. If existing vendors get new inventories immediately every time they are assigned to a different stall, that's also a valid experiment. It's outside the scope of this particular question, but it's still valid methodology, as long as everything is documented. Oh, I'm also going to assign a fresh settler, check their inventory, then assign then to a new stall.

Comment: @Dallium, controls exist in code...A control is the base/standard scenario. That's how programming works; It doesn't need to be "natural phenomena". There are still [potentially] a huge amount of variables in code as well, **definitely** not able to be ignore even a single one. That's why unit tests exist (and other types of course). I deal with this daily and I cannot stress how much you *could* miss by not having a fresh settler control. (although you said you are testing that, I appreciate it). I'm just getting nitpicky from a programmer's/tester standpoint, the terminology isn't the point.

Comment: @DangerZone controls do exist in code, but in this scenario, the control would be a settler you do nothing to. We already know that a settler not assigned to a store isn't a vendor. A fresh settler assigned to a store isn't in the control group, they're being experimented upon. As for the variables in the code, without access to the source code, our ability to identify, and test and compensate for "environmental" and/or extraneous variables is essentially nonexistent. We can either hope the code works consistently and experiment, or give up.

Comment: @Dallium, that's only correct if your assumption that settlers and vendors are the same game object (very simply speaking). If a "settler" is "converted" to a "vender", then no, an unassigned settler is definitely not a control for testing venders. Which is why I suggested testing a fresh vender since all the "vender variables" are fresh (only if my assumption is correct of course). But you're right. Without code it's pointless. We can discuss in chat if you like, otherwise continuing this here isn't beneficial to future readers since this is all speculation.

Comment: Yes please stop it with the comment spam :). Im getting to many notifications lol.

Answer (score 3):

After extensive testing, I have detemined the inventory is of the shop itself, not the settler, and is stocked immediately when the store is created.

**However,** one of the more questionable design choices was the decision to have both a **Trade** and **Barter** dialogue option on the same menu for settlement vendors.

Trade is the left option, which allows you to access the settlers inventory to equip them.

Barter is the bottom option, which allows you to purchase from them.

Doctors are notable exceptions, the bottom dialogue option allows you to receive medical treatment, while the left one is Barter.

Comment: Not sure how that's a questionable design choice. Trade is used to give the settler things, just like a companion. I have a settlement in Sanctuary where all my shop tenders are in Minuteman uniforms with upgraded weapons and armor. Adds a touch of class.

Comment: @DCShannon the naming is confusing, especially as at least two of the greetings vendors give is effectively "want to trade?" Even knowing better I've selected the trade. I could totally understand someone parsing that menu, getting to trade and assuming it means buying and selling, without ever realizing barter was an option. It should have had a different interface.